# "Sub optimally" vs "sub-optimally", which should be preferred?

Tags: hyphenation

When writing "the part performs sub optimally", should that instead be "the part performs sub-optimally"?

Comment: You can't make "sub" a separate word unless you are referring to an underwater vehicle (or other standalone meaning).

Comment: Thanks! That is what I originally thought. As I mentioned below, I relied to heavily on Chrome's spell checker.

Comment: If you rely on electronic spell-checkers at all, you are indeed relying *too* heavily on them.

Comment: @choster Well this is embarrassing. You can blame that one on Swype keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

There is a word "suboptimally" Here it is in the [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suboptimally) dictionary.

So thee is no need for a hyphen or a space.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I should've checked harder; Chrome's spell check told me it wasn't actually a word.